# Brownian motion expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, stopping-times

I have issue resolving this exercise :

If $W_t$ is a Brownian motion we define $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ such that

$$
X_t= \begin{cases} W_t & \text{if } \forall s\le t, W_s>-1, \\
-1 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Can you compute $E[X_1]$

If someone have a clue. i know this is related to stopping time and Doob theorem maybe.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i define $ \tau= inf \{ t \ge 0 \text{ such that} : W_t>-1 \} $ is a stopping time and by definition of $\tau$  , $W_{\tau}>-1$ and by definition of $X$ we have $X_t=W_\tau$ and therefore $E[X_t]=E[W_{min(\tau,t)}]$ but then i don't know what to do ( for $t=1$)

Comment: is this the good intuition? is this the good stopping time?

Comment: $\mathbb E[X_1] = \mathbb E[  X_1 \cdot 1_{\{\tau \le 1 \}}] + \mathbb E[X_1 \cdot 1_{\{\tau > 1 \}}]= -\mathbb P(\tau \le 1) + \mathbb E[W_1 \cdot 1_{\{ W_1* > -1 \}}$ where $W_1* = \sup_{s \in [0,1]}W_s$. Do you already covered distribution of $\tau$ and vector $(W_1,W_1*)$? Those can be calculated by reflection principle

Comment: thanks but it seems a little bit overcomplicated. I think the solution is easier.

Comment: Okay, right, it slipped my mind, obviously it is easier. Process $W=(W_t)$ is a martingale, hence by Doob $W^{\tau} = (W_{\min(\tau,t)})$ is a martingale, too. By that $\mathbb E[X_1] = \mathbb E[W_{\min(\tau,1)}] = \mathbb E[W_{\min(\tau,0)}] = 0$

Comment: Thanks are you sure the Doob theorem is well applied here?

Comment: If $X=(X_t)$ is a continuous (right or left continuous almost surely is enough) martingale w.r.t $(\mathcal F_t)$, $\tau$ is a stopping time, then $(X_{\min(\tau,t)})$ is a martingale w.r.t $(\mathcal F_t)$. I applied this version.

Comment: ok thanks. this is the right answer.